# Brown POS Tagger in Python

Tags: python, nltk

I am currently working on a text predictor project that uses some basic nltk stuff along with some data processing. I am trying to tag words using the [nltk.pos_tag](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag.html) function to tag words using the Brown Corpus. However, the tagset option for pos_tag is not working when given the brown option. I am wondering if a) anyone knows how to make it work like this, or b) anyone knows a well trained and working POS tagger using the Brown Corpus tags.

Comment: Refer [How To Ask On Stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and Take a Tour

Comment: Post some code that you might have tried to run.